# The difference between using a self invoking function and document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come this doesn't work in loading header content...

```
(function ($) {
    var mheaderwrapper = '<div id="header"></div><div class="header-menu"></div>';
    var mheadercontent = '/shop/Pages/global_header.html';
    var mmenucontent = '/shop/Pages/global_megamenu.html';
    var mjqueryhover = 'js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js';
    var mjquerymenu = 'js/jquery.custom-menu.js';
    $('#wrapper').prepend(mheaderwrapper);
    $('#header').load(mheadercontent);
    $('.header-menu').load(mmenucontent, function(){
       $.getScript(mjqueryhover);
       $.getScript(mjquerymenu);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

but this does...

```
  $.mheader = function() {
    var mheaderwrapper = '<div id="header"></div><div class="header-menu"></div>';
    var mheadercontent = '/shop/Pages/global_header.html';
    var mmenucontent = '/shop/Pages/global_megamenu.html';
    var mjqueryhover = 'js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js';
    var mjquerymenu = 'js/jquery.custom-menu.js';
    $('#wrapper').prepend(mheaderwrapper);
    $('#header').load(mheadercontent);
    $('.header-menu').load(mmenucontent, function(){
       $.getScript(mjqueryhover);
       $.getScript(mjquerymenu);
    });
   }

$(function() {
  $.mheader();
});
```

Comment: This doesn look right... `$function() {
  $.mheader();
});`

Comment: my mistake - i rushed in typing that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This :

```
(function ($) {....})(jQuery);
```

executes immediately, and only maps `jQuery` to `$` to make sure the dollar sign really is "jQuery" within the self executing function. It's **not** a "DOM ready" function.

This:

```
$(function() {....});
```

will wait until the DOM is ready before any code is executed.

You can use the second one inside the first one :

```
(function ($) {
    $(function() {
        //code here
    });
})(jQuery);
```

to do both!

Comment: You can use the second one in this way to also do both: `jQuery(function($){ /* code here */ });`

Answer (score 2):

When you have a function in the `<head>` section like that, it is executing immediately, and is doing so before your HTML elements have started loading. Your elements `#wrapper`, `#header`, and anything with the `.header-menu` class do not yet exist at the time your code is executing, which is why it fails.

In the second example, using the `domready` event delays the firing of your code until after the DOM is ready (and your HTML elements exist), so the code works.

By the way,

```
$(function() {
    // executes when DOM is ready
});
```

is just a shortcut for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // executes when DOM is ready
});
```

The above examples are specifically functionality provided by jQuery. Don't confuse the former with the immediately-executing function structure, which is pure JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    // executes NOW
})();
```

See [adeneo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13615589/74757) for how to properly combine the two.

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready` actually runs **after** the `DOM` is created.

Self-invoking functions run instantly if inserted into `<head>` section, before the DOM is constructed.